# Nested query in Firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore database structure like this: 
(Articles is a collection, everything inside is arrays)

```
Articles:
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "reports": [
            {
                "locations": [
                    {
                        "location": "Sydney",
                        "country": "Australia"
                    },
                    {
                        "location": "Perth",
                        "country": "Australia"
                    }
                ],
            },
            {
                "locations": [
                    {
                        "location": "King County, Washington",
                        "country": "USA"
                    }
                ],
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "reports": [
            {
                "locations": [
                    {
                        "location": "Brisbane",
                        "country": "Australia"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'd like to create a query to return all Articles that mention a specific country.
Am I better off restructuring my database?

Comment: Can you indicate what are collections in this structure, vs array fields?

Comment: Articles is a collection, everything within it is an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Firestore's `array-contains` queries can get you close to this, you can't use them in your current data model as you're nesting arrays.

To allow the use-case you'll at the very least need to unnest one of those arrays into a subcollection of each article, so:

```
Articles (collection)
  $article
    reports (collection)
      $report (document with a locations array)
```

At that point you can use a collection group query to search all `reports` collections, and then `array-contains` to find the relevant report documents:

```
var ref = firebase.firestore().collectionGroup("reports");
ref.where("locations", "array-contains", { location: "Sydney", country: "Australia" })
```

---

Never mind the below answer, which assumed you had only one level of array...

<strike>This type of query should be possible, as far as I can see, using the `array-contains` operator. Keeping in mind that you need to specify the entire array item.</strike>

So something like:

```
collectionRef.where("reports.locations", "array-contains", 
                        { location: "Sydney", country: "Australia" })
```

Comment: Is there a way of returning the parent (Article) of the report? I'm doing this currently:

`const rec = await db.collectionGroup("reports").where("locations", "array-contains", { location: "Sydney", country: "Australia" }).get()`

`res.send(rec.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))`

I'd like to send back the Articles with the Reports within

Comment: Yup, you can get the parent from `DocumentSnapshot.ref.collection.doc`.